# How to Rerun the TextStream.AtEndOfStream

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, do-while, filesystemobject

I'm successfully running the code below to display a text file to the browser, line by line:

```
<% 
    Filename = "/pages/test.txt"
    Set FSO = server.createObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Filepath = Server.MapPath(Filename)

    Set file = FSO.GetFile(Filepath)
    Set TextStream = file.OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)  

    Do While Not TextStream.AtEndOfStream  
            Line = TextStream.readline
            Response.Write Line & "<br>"
    Loop 

    Set TextStream = nothing
    Set FSO = nothing
%>
```

I'd like to run the `Do While Not TextStream.AtEndOfStream` loop one more time, right before the `Set TextStream = nothing` statement.

Turns out I cannot "just" copy the `Do While` loop and place it below the first instance.  There are no results from the `TextStream` anymore.

Is there a way to reset the `TextStream` object back to the beginning of the stream?

I could store the lines in an array and utilize that, but I wanted to see if there was an easier route.

Comment: Not with the `TextStream` object but if you switched to using the `ADO.Stream` object once you read the stream you could use the 'Position` property to set stream position to `0` and read the stream again. `ADODB.Stream` is far more flexible in that regard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way to manually position the pointer in a `TextStream` object. You can `Close` the `TextStream` and reopen it. Or, you can just read the file once into an array, as you implied. Considering you're outputting the entirety of the file to a web page, I'll assume it's not incredibly large and, therefore, storing it in an array would not be too memory intensive.

```vb
' Create an array containing each line from the text file...
a = Split(file.OpenAsTextStream(1, -2).ReadAll(), vbCrLf)

For i = 0 To UBound(a)
    Response.Write a(i) & "<br>"
Next

' Repeat the process...
For i = 0 To UBound(a)
    Response.Write a(i) & "<br>"
Next
```

You could even replace the line endings with `<br>` and write it in one operation:

```vb
strText = Replace(file.OpenAsTextStream(1, -2).ReadAll(), vbCrLf, "<br>")

Response.Write strText
Response.Write strText    ' Write it again
```

Comment: Yeah, I suspected as much.  But your example seems doable and easy too.  thanks

Comment: @coffeemonitor as @Bond pointed, use this method only if the file size is reasonable. Otherwise you'll be in trouble with memory related problems. In such cases feel free to open, read and close several times. Using `TextStream` object is definitely a memory-friendly way, reading all the lines into an array nor using `Adodb.Stream` are not. I think this is very important for a healthy working web application.

Comment: @Kul-Tigin [Tired of FileSystemObject? Use the Stream Object Instead!](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/083100-1.shtml). I'd also be interested in the evidence you have to support the claim that `TextStream` is a more *"memory-friendly"* option then `ADODB.Stream`??

Comment: @Kul-Tigin I agree that it is always better to close and re-open but suggesting `TextStream` is any more memory efficient then `ADODB.Stream` is nonsense.

Comment: @Lankymart nonsense? I wouldn't say that :) I speak from experience. It's easy to test. Adodb.Stream's LoadFromFile reads entire file into memory in order to create an IStream object. FileSystemObject's TextStream does the same thing by reading chunk by chunk. I will not prove it to you, you're capable to test it.

Comment: @Kul-Tigin I didn't realise `TextStream` was chunked and finding any definitive statement on the web has yielded nothing. To be honest I've used both methods for years and have not found either to be overly efficient. Will have to do some more research.

Answer (score 0):

### Limitations of the `TextStream` Object

The `TextStream` object in the Visual Basic Script Runtime is very limited in what it can do.

- Reading is Forward Only which means you cannot go back to an earlier point in the stream.
- Writing is all or nothing, when a file is open in `ForWriting` mode the contents of the file is truncated before being overwritten *(as [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31572446/how-to-rerun-the-textstream-atendofstream/31590219?noredirect=1#comment51176788_31590219) to avoid this use `ForAppending`)*.

### Is There Another Way?

#### Introducing the `ADODB.Stream` Object!

Fortunately `ADODB` provides a far more flexible streaming object called `ADODB.Stream` which among other things allows you to open a file *(text or binary)* and control the `Position` property allowing you to read from an earlier point in the stream.

Something like;

```
<%
Dim TextStream, Filename, Filepath    

Filename = "/pages/test.txt"
Filepath = Server.MapPath(Filename)

Set TextStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
Call TextStream.Open()
TextStream.Type = adTypeText

Call TextStream.LoadFromFile(Filepath)

Do While Not TextStream.EOS
  Line = TextStream.ReadText(adReadLine)
  Call Response.Write(Line & "<br>")
Loop

'Reset stream back to start of the stream
TextStream.Position = 0

Do While Not TextStream.EOS
  Line = TextStream.ReadText(adReadLine)
  Call Response.Write(Line & "<br>")
Loop    

Call TextStream.Close()
Set TextStream = Nothing
%>
```

Obviously this is just a quick example *(untested)* of how to work with the `ADODB.Stream`. It's worth noting that you can improve this by moving the `TextStream.Position = 0` and `Do While` loop into a separate function that can be re-used and cuts down on the duplication. For the purposes of this answer however have kept it simple.

---

### More Information

- [MSDN Library - Stream Object (ADO)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675032(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Using METADATA to Import DLL Constants](https://web.archive.org/web/20210417073339/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/110199-1.shtml) *(For avoiding issues with Named Constants used in this example)*

Comment: bear in mind that, there's another option `ForAppending` to avoid truncating. `ForWriting` is not only option to write.

Comment: @Kul-Tigin Yes but `ForAppending` isn't useful in this case, I was merely pointing out the behaviour of `ForWriting` that might throw some people. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Glad to see you've adapted to offering alternatives, Lankymart.